# Java code reads UTF-8 text incorrectly

Tags: java, utf-8, tokenize, hebrew

I'm having a problem reading UTF-8 characters in my code (running on Eclipse).

I have a file `text` which has a few lines in it, for example:

```
אך  1234
```

**NOTE**: There is a `\t` before the word, and the word should appear on the left, the number on the right... I don't know how to reverse them here, sorry.

That is,  a Hebrew word and then a number.

I need to separate the word from the number somehow. I tried this:

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(text));
        String content;

        while ((content = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            String delims = "[ ]+";
            String[] tokens = content.split(delims);
        }
```

The problem is that for some reason, the code reads `content` (the first line in the file) as follows:

```
אך\t1234
```

...meaning that the space isn't in its correct place.

I suppose I could tokenize the text using the `\t`, but I'm not sure I should do it, as the file isn't being read correctly...

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Thanks so much :-)

Comment: I imagine the file is being read right-to-left instead of left-to-right. Is there a byte-order-mark at the top of the file?

Comment: Thanks @MarkElliot, but I don't think that's the issue... It's reading it in the correct order (I'm not able to write it correctly in the question). I't just that the `\t` is supposed to be _before_ the word, and not between the tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are matching a space when there actually is a tab there?

Can you try this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(text));
String content;

while ((content = br.readLine()) != null) 
{
    String delims = "\\s";
    String[] tokens = content.split(delims);
}
```

Comment: Hey that worked!!! How? If it sees a tab there, how did it work with `\s` (which I understand is a space)? Thank you @Stijn!!!! :) :)

Comment: Actually, `\s` is any kind of whitespace...? Then that explains why it works now , but not why java is reading the file incorrectly... (there is no tab between the words in the file). Still, thanks :-)

Comment: @Cheshie `\s` is a regular expression matching a whitespace character. A whitespace character can be: a space character, a tab character, a carriage return character, a new line character, a vertical tab character or a form feed character.