# space in right to left languages in a word file c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, right-to-left, persian

I'm working on a C# software, it generates some texts in a right to left language(persian). I use code below:

```
s += char.ConvertFromUtf32(32);
```

to add a space between words and at the end of the whole procedure, I will save the doc file. Although the saved text is looking good, but the space character is not a right to left space and make some problems like bad placed dots.like picture:

> [image: bad placed dots]

I can fix it by replacing all the spaces in the saved file with changing the keyboard language to farsi and then type space. which makes th example like below:

> [image: changing the keyboard language to farsi and then type space]

I have extracted the persian space char by using the following code which is 32.

```
char[] arr=s.ToCharArray();
```

and the space char is 32.
so, please help me how can I fix it.

Comment: I cannot see any difference. What you need help with?

Comment: the place of the dot. I have just changed the space after the dot and the dot position will be correct visually.

Comment: Sounds like a classic Right-to-left issue. Is there already, or can you add, a Right-to-left mark?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark

See also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290449/java-code-reads-utf-8-text-incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

actually, I found the answer. I used Spire.Doc to simplify the process of making word files, adding this line of code will make it completely correct.
`TextRange tr = paragraph.AppendText("Spire.Doc");
            tr.CharacterFormat.Bidi = true;`
Thnx u guys for your help.